# Exterior products of Admissible Representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, admissible-representation

I have an $SL(n,R)$ admissible representation $V$, and I wish to consider $V\wedge V$.  Is it possible that $V\wedge V$ is not admissible?  What if $V$ is irreducible?

As a specific example, consider $SL(3,R)$ acting on $L^{3/2}(R^2)$ isometrically via linear fractional transformations (where we think of $R^2$ as $RP^2$).  I.e., for $A\in SL(3,R)$ and $v\in RP^2$ write $Av$ for the linear fractional transformation induced by $A$.  Then the action is $f(x)\mapsto |J A|^{2/3} f(Ax)$, and $JA$ denotes the Jacobian of this map.

Let $V$ denote this representation.  I think this is irreducible and admissible (though would like comments on that, too).  Is it easy to see that $V\wedge V$ is admissible?  How can I decompose it into irreducibles?

Thanks!